# how to check theme color in code in bitnami Wordpress in AWS Lightsail using style.css file

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

In AWS lightsail Wordpress, in home folder of the server machine, I found

```
bitnami_application_password  bitnami_credentials  htdocs  stack
```

Where I can find themes/twentytwenty/style.css file,  so that I can change background color of wordpress homepage.

Comment: Hi, if possible don't change the theme's basic files as you will lose the changes when the theme updates. Have you considered using Wordpress's built in custom style system available in the dashboard under Appearance?

Comment: I want to know how to change it from code. Which folder has style.css file? Also how can I change database setting from code if I use LIghtsail to create a shared database?

Answer (score 0):

The path you are looking for is:
/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/style.css